# Query Error: Expecting right square bracket, found 'ORDER BY ClosedDate desc '

Tags: apex, soql, query

I have a query in my apex code:

```
oldcrashes=[SELECT Id,OCTO_End_User_Service_Contract__c,OCTO_Closure_Reason_Text__c,OCTO_Validated_By_OTP__c,ClosedDate,Status 
                    FROM Case WHERE RecordType.Name='CRASH DOSSIER – PRO ACTIVE NOTIFICATION'
                    AND Status='Closed' 
                    AND OCTO_End_User_Service_Contract__c=:currentCase.OCTO_End_User_Service_Contract__c
                    ORDER BY ClosedDate desc 
                    LIMIT 3];
```

The system when i try to save throws the error:

> expecting right square bracket, found 'ORDER BY ClosedDate desc '

I don't understand why. Someone can help me please?

Comment: Nothing stands out for me. Suggest you try removing terms one by one from the where clause to isolate the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try to put currentCase.OCTO_End_User_Service_Contract__c into a variable.
And run the query changing

```
OCTO_End_User_Service_Contract__c=:currentCase.OCTO_End_User_Service_Contract__c
```

into

```
AND OCTO_End_User_Service_Contract__c=: myVar
```

Comment: Done.Same error

Comment: What type of field is OCTO_End_User_Service_Contract__c ? If you delete this condition, it works ?

Comment: is a custom field.

Comment: yes, i know, but it a formula field ?

Comment: no it's a lookup field. I figured out what was the problem. I copied the query from previous apex code, but somehow the copy/paste failed. I tried again with copy/paste and now the query works properly.

Comment: Good  @L.benedettini